# DotNetNuke 5 - Are there any best practices for migrating existing aspx-based website into DotNetNuke

Tags: asp.net, web, migration, dotnetnuke

our website resides on iis-server and is completely written with Expression Web using templates and pure html-pages based on those templates. There's also some slight functionality built using c# in code behind.

Now i've been looking into DotNetNuke 5 as an alternative, so that our content editors (no tech bg) wouldn't have such a hard time when doing updates, adding pages and so forth. Naturally we would like to keep our finely tuned css-layout and maybe add some additional functionality later, probably using DNN modules.

I'll begin with a broad question:

**Are there any best practices for migrating into DotNetNuke from an existing website?**

Any articles, blogs, webcasts, books etc. related to this question would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.datasprings.com/Resources/ArticlesInformation/MigratetoDotNetNuke/tabid/737/language/en-US/Default.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/843931.aspx

The last one is a bit older - not sure if these will help - I think the thing to do is sit down understand how DNN does its pages and menu etc and then map it out on paper

planning planning planning -----------------

No matter what going from html to dynamic system like DNN is going to take grunt work

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I guess this is just what i'll need to do. I've done some additional googling, and there doesn't seem to be any easy way to achieve my goal. No "import site"-button here :-) I upvoted, but i'll leave this unanswered for now. Maybe someone comes up with the definitive guide!

Comment: I decided to mark this as answer. I doubt there will be any definite guide for this specific process, as nobody will probably create a program to import custom asp.net site to DNN.